# Is there a significant difference between using "self = this" and bind(this) for inner functions?

Tags: javascript, performance

In JavaScript when using inner functions that are callbacks (e.g. AJAX calls) they run in their own environment (`this` is the window object), and doesn't know the `this` as where they are written. And I have seen 2 solutions for that:

- Using `self` or `that`: (done by auto boxing the `self` variable)

```js
var Obj = function(){
    var a = 1;

    var subFunc = function(){
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'something.x',
            success: function(data){alert(self);}
        });
    }

    return {
        subtract : subFunc
    }
};

var o = new Obj();
o.substract();
```

- Using `bind` command: (I'm not sure how this is done)

```js
var Obj = function(){
    var a = 1;

    var subFunc = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'something.x',
            success: function(data){alert(this);}.bind(this)
        });
    }

    return {
        subtract : subFunc
    }
};

var o = new Obj();
o.substract();
```

What is the difference when the interpreter actually starts the interpretation? What impact does this have on performance?

Comment: Have you tried to [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/) it?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `.bind(self)` instead of `.bind(this)`?

Comment: @JakubKonecki No, I guess it should be `this` since it is called within object literal, not in a function.

Comment: @VisioN I don't know what that is. I will look into it.

Comment: @JakubKonecki That was a copy-paste mistake that the variable was there. The code also works like it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind is generally preferred by experienced JS developers (at least where I've worked).

JavaScript scoping is hard to understand at first, because "this" is not included in the closure when defining a new function. It might make you want to give up and just create a new local variable to point to it, but you're limiting yourself if you do this.

The advantage of bind, once you get used to it, is that you're using the language consistently.

Do you write a lot of classes in JS? Once you get used to bind, you know why calling a function on an object is different from setting that function to a local variable and then calling it, because you are always thinking about scope. You always know where "this" comes from, because you declare it.

You also avoid the annoyance of declaring, and reading, repeated "self" and "that" variables cluttering up your code base.

The disadvantage of bind is that it's not generally available. But it's very educational to write a polyfill for it (or just find one online), and then you never have to worry about it again!

I doubt that there are performance implications either way. Certainly not in typical daily use.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit to using `var self` vs `.bind()` was recently pointed out to me by a friend.

For Exe:

```
function () {
  var self = this;

  $('selector').map(function () {
    this.attr('href');

    self.doThis();
  });
}
```

This way you are able to use two `this` scopes. I agree with the other answer that it can clutter things up, but I suppose it has its place.

Heres a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-self-bb)
There is virtually zero difference. Then again, its an extremely simple test.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up not using binding, I would recommend using `that` rather than `self`.

That's because `self` is a valid global variable (in `window.self`).
I used to name my scope `self`, and one day I forgot the `var self = this` line... This was not as easy to debug as you may expect. I now use `that` or `me`, or more often than not use binding.